# Get index of a particular item from observable collection - UWP c#

Tags: c#, uwp, observablecollection

I want to get the index of a particular item from my observable collection. I have a class like below.

```
namespace TestClass
{
public class ClassRoomList
{
public int ClassID{ get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<CurrentStudentsList> CurrentStudentsArray { get; set; }
}

public class CurrentStudentsList
{
public string StudentName { get; set; }
public string StudentID { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<StudentsMarksList> StudentsMarksArray { get; set;            }

}
public class StudentsMarksList
{
public string MarkInEnglish { get; set; }
public string MarkInMaths{ get; set; }
}
```

And my observable collection is defined as

```
 public static ObservableCollection<ClassRoomList> _ClassRoomList = new ObservableCollection<ClassRoomList>();
```

How can I get the index of StudentsMarksArray, which has StudentID=555?

Comment: Have you tried `CurrentStudentsArray.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentId == 555)` followed by an `IndexOf` for your object?

Comment: What do you mean with "index of StudentsMarkArray"? Its a property in your CurrentStudentsList, so it doesn't has an index